# Why is Spotify API displaying my data to other users?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotipy

I created a small app. A part of it displays a list of a user's playlists for them to select from. First I had issues with users being able to log in again as I had a cache folder in my git repository that was pushing old tokens. I deleted that cache file along with the pycache folder. Since then, when a user is taken to the page to select one of their playlists, it is showing my personal spotify playlists rather than theirs! I have no idea what has happened! I haven't altered any code in the app.py file. About an hour ago, when a user first logged in, it was showing their playlists. Until I deleted the cache files. Any clues on what could be the issue?

Here is the code from the relevant pages. /toptracks is the redirect uri which redirects to the /selectedplaylist page. This is where a list of the logged in user's playlists should be displayed as a list. Instead, my playlists are being showed...

```
app= Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.secret_key= appKey
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME']= 'A Cookie'
TOKEN_INFO= 'token_info'

def create_spotify_oauth():
    return SpotifyOAuth(
         client_id= SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
         client_secret= SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
         redirect_uri='https://myurl.com/toptracks',
         scope= 'user-top-read'
    )

         

@app.route("/")
def index():
    sp_oauth= create_spotify_oauth()
    auth_url= sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    return render_template('index.html', auth_url=auth_url)
@app.route('/toptracks')
def redirector():
    sp_oauth= create_spotify_oauth()
    session.clear()
    code= request.args.get('code')
    token_info= sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
    print(token_info)
    session[TOKEN_INFO]= token_info
    return redirect('/selectplaylist')

@app.route('/selectplaylist')
def selectPlaylist():
    try:
        token_info= get_token()
    except:
        print('try logging in again')
        redirect('/')
    sp= spotipy.Spotify(auth=token_info['access_token'])
    user= sp.current_user()['id']
    allPlaylists= sp.user_playlists(user=user,limit=50)['items']
    playName= [[i.get('name'),i.get('id')] for i in allPlaylists]
    playId= [i.get('id') for i in allPlaylists]
    return render_template('selectPlaylist.html',playName=playName,playId=playId)

def get_token():
    token_info= session.get(TOKEN_INFO, None)
    if not token_info:
        raise 'exception'
    now = int(time.time())
    is_expired= token_info['expires_at'] - now < 60
    if (is_expired):
        sp_oauth= create_spotify_oauth()
        token_info= sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(token_info['refresh_token'])
    return token_info
```

I tried to remove some other cache files but this didn't solve anything. I'm not sure what else I could try as the code itself seems to be fine. My confusion about what I could try is compounded by the fact that it worked fine just hours ago.

Comment: Here's code of a working Flask app: https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py

Comment: Please add all the code. Functions like `create_spotify_oauth()` are missing, so we are not able to replicate your issues easily.

Comment: @Ximzend I've updated the code to show the Oauth functions too now! Does this help? I've set TOKEN_INFO earlier as a variable, would this still require quotations in session[ ]  as you suggested?

Comment: @Ximzend still having issues :( any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you to use app.py (as mention above) as a starting point, because I know that code works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused by Spotify automatically creating a .cache file in my system. I applied this cleanup() function all over my module, whenever pulling spotify user data, and it fixed everything:

```
def cleanup():
    cache_file = '.cache'
    if os.path.exists(cache_file):
        os.remove(cache_file)
```